# AppModelV2: how to get signed in user automatically using Azure

Tags: passport.js, azure-active-directory, openid-connect, adal, passport-azure-ad

I'm trying out the new model for unified app authentication using passport-azurea-ad from this reference https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/active-directory-v2-devquickstarts-node-web

The integration is successful,but every time I do login,I get redirected to a page where I get to choose from my existing microsoft accounts or add a new one.
 Why is the session or account not getting  picked up automatically, if the  user is already logged into his azure or microsoft account?
 My requirement is user session should be picked up automatically(not for the first time where  he gives consent) if he is logged into his azure account or micrososft account[image]

this page needs to be avoided , if he is already signed in

Answer (score 3):

The reason is a technical limitation.  Let me see if I can explain briefly:

- When a request comes to the v2 endpoint (login.microsoftonline.com), the v2 endpoint can not detect the presence of an existing consumer account session (login.live.com).
- Therefore, the v2 endpoint must make a query (via an iframe hosted on the login.microsoftonline.com page) to login.live.com to detect if a consumer session exists or not.
- If a consumer session exists, the v2 endpoint should show the user an 'account selection' screen, like the one you depict in the question.
- If a consumer session does not exist, and the user only has one business session, it could auto-login the user with that business account.  However, by this time the user has likely already been waiting for a second or so for the query to login.live.com to complete.  It might be a strange user experience if the page auto-completed after a second.

The v2 endpoint could definitely show a loading spinner or something to hold the user until the decision can be made, but it was decided that having the user click a tile was an acceptable alternative.

Comment: @dstrockis The app requiring authentication could send the last known username to the v2 endpoint as a param (even whether it's consumer account or not) and the endpoint could first attempt to determine if that user has an active session and auto-login. Would this be a feasible alternative?

Comment: Yes! Try using the query parameter `&login_hint=`. It should have exactly the behavior you describe

Comment: I should also add that if you use the `/consumers` or `/organizations` endpoints, SSO will automatically occur when a single account is signed in.

Comment: @dstockis - if my understanding is right login_hint will only prefill the email but not take the account and auto-login right? and for auto-login if I use the query parameter prompt: "none", it still shows selection page for various accounts.Can you shed some light onto this.
 Based on https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/active-directory-v2-protocols-oauth-code